# SvelteKit: How to access Firebase authentication state from the server

Tags: firebase, svelte, sveltekit

I'm managing authentication state in a readable store which is grouped with a promise that resolves when the auth state is known (either signed in or out). The store is set internally via `onAuthStateChange`.

I'm trying to access this auth state from the server (`+layout.server.ts` and `+page.server.ts`) so that I can redirect the user to a sign-in page if they aren't authenticated, or load data from the database if (and only if) they are. No matter what I try, whenever I access this store from the server, its value is always null. I think this is because Firebase is only supposed to run on the client, although I'm not sure. Is there any way I can access this store from the server, or change my implementation so that Firebase runs in the server and passes auth state to the client? [This](https://jeroenpelgrims.com/access-the-firebase-auth-user-in-sveltekit-server-side/) blog post explains pretty much exactly what I want to do, but the solution here seems more complicated than it needs to be.

I've tried moving Firebase initialization code to the server (in both `hooks.server.ts` and `+layout.server.ts`), but there's no way for me to pass the auth object to the client because it can't be serialized (I get an error explaining this when I try to return it from a load function in `+page.server.ts`). I've also tried to handle authentication only using client-side code, but the server is responsible for loading data from the database, so in this case there's no way for me to verify a valid authentication state from the server.

Comment: Blog post you referenced explains all in details and code there is not overcomplicated. What answer do you expect?

Comment: Verifying auth state before a database call strikes me as a very standard problem that should have a well-defined solution. Adding a Firebase service account and saving auth state to cookies feels like an over-engineered solution relative to the problem at hand, but if this is the correct way to do it then so be it.

Comment: firebase expects you to use firestore or the firebase real time database, which work better with firebase auth.

if you need to access auth state on your server to call a non-firebase service, this mechanically make it more complex, it's not that surprising.

Comment: I am using firebase realtime database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

author of the blog post you linked here.

You are correct in that the [firebase client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) is only supposed to run on the client. If you want to access the Firebase services server-side you're supposed to use [Firebase admin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin).

In my post I'm working around these limitations that firebase sets and unfortunately you do need that much code.
You are forced to do all the authentication in the frontend (firebase-client) and only afterwards you can inform the backend of the user info. (through the cookie)

Before I wrote this the ideal solution I had in my head was this:

- Send the user to a login page that lists all the possible login providers.
- The user chooses one and logs in.
- the user gets redirected to a callback page where we can do something with the auth data in the backend.

I do think that something like this flow is possible if you're using [custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens). But I'm sure that will be a whole load of even more complicated code.

Comment: Thank you for your response, and for sharing your solution in the first place!

Comment: Thanks for the informative blog! OOC, have you tried using `hooks.ts`? I haven't tried it myself but that's what I hear lends itself well to JWT-based auth and such.